# Sikuli is failing on image click because not able to find

Tags: selenium, sikuli

i tried number of ways but still getting an error while trying to click on image.
My code is as below:

```
public void sikuli() throws FindFailed, Exception {
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='data visualization']")));

     Pattern pattern = new Pattern("lightsolution/Screenshots/C2.PNG").similar((float) 0.7);
     Screen screen = new Screen();
     try {

    screen.click(pattern); 

    }catch (FindFailed e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
     }
```

It run successfully  but i removed the captured image and tried to create new image. and now its not working with number of different captured images.

> Tried with screen.click(screen.wait(open,10)); Also tried  with

```
if(screen.find(pattern)!=null){ 
 screen.mouseMove(pattern); 
 screen.click(pattern);
```

Error:

```
FindFailed: can not find P(C:/Selenium/workspace/lightsolution/C2.PNG) S: 0.7 in S(0)[0,0 1366x768]
  Line 2189, in file Region.java

 at org.sikuli.script.Region.handleFindFailedShowDialog(Region.java:2189)
 at org.sikuli.script.Region.handleFindFailed(Region.java:2134)
 at org.sikuli.script.Region.wait(Region.java:2546)
 at org.sikuli.script.Region.find(Region.java:2205)
 at org.sikuli.script.Region.getLocationFromTarget(Region.java:3067)
 at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3534)
 at org.sikuli.script.Region.click(Region.java:3519)
```

The dependency i am using:

```
    groupId com.sikulix/groupId
    artifactIdsikulixapi/artifactId
    version1.1.0/version
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

> 1. Try to take images from Sikuli IDE.
> 2. Refresh and clean your project after changing each images.
> 3. Try giving whole absolute path of image not relative just to check image is getting 
>      identified or not.
> 4. Check you are correctly switching to frames before clicking on pattern.
> 5. Put wait in between switching frames and clicking on pattern.
> 6. Sikui is image based so for different computer resolution you need different images.
> 7. Check nothing is connected to your laptop ports(charger,headphone etc while executing) -this personally helps me while dealing with FindFailed exception.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks,  i will try.